# How to Zip File By Month with 7Zip

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

I have below PowerShell Script and it will zip all files into one zip file with current month as zip filename (June 2017.7z).

```
# set folder path
    $dump_path = "C:\Users\Desktop\02_2017"

    # set min age of files
    $max_days = "-30"

    # get the current date
    $curr_date = Get-Date

    # determine how far back we go based on current date
    $zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

    # filter files
    $files = Get-ChildItem $dump_path | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) }

    $groups = Get-ChildItem $dump_path | 
        Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) } | 
        group {"{0:MMMM} {0:yyyy}" -f $_.CreationTime}

    ForEach ($group in $groups) {
        ForEach($file in $group.Group){
            & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2 ($group.Name + ".7z") $file.FullName
            Remove-Item $file.FullName -exclude *.ps1
        }
    }
```

How do I modify the script so that it will zip all files which have been created in each month separately? For example, aaa1, aaa2, aaa3 will be zipped to aug_2016.7z, bbb1, bbb2, bbb3 will be zipped to feb_2017.7z and so on then delete archived files.

```
8/29/2016  11:09 PM          88583 aaa1.log
8/30/2016   6:06 AM          88590 aaa2.log
8/30/2016   7:07 AM          88586 aaa3 .log
 2/1/2017   6:03 AM         179412 bbb1.log
 2/1/2017   7:03 AM         179285 bbb2.log
 2/1/2017   8:03 AM         179418 bbb3.log
 5/3/2017   6:31 PM          95764 ccc1.log
 5/3/2017   8:33 PM          95605 ccc2.log
 5/3/2017  10:34 PM          95391 ccc3.log
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
Added Remove-Item $file.FullName -exclude *.ps1 to remove archived files.

Comment: Your script looks at the past 30 days, is that what you intend? or do you want by month (Jun, Jul, etc.)?

Comment: TheIncorrigible1, thank you for pointing that out. I need to archive all files which are older than 30 days and delete files after archive. This script file will be execute monthly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my problem. Thank you for your help guys. Below is the script if anyone out there needs it.

> ```
> # set folder path
> $log_path = "C:\Users\pdo\Desktop\02_2017\log\*.log"
> $zip_path = "C:\Users\pdo\Desktop\02_2017\log\*.7z"
> $target_path = "C:\Users\pdo\Desktop\02_2017\log\"
>
> # set min age of files
> $max_days = "-30"
> $delete_max_days = "-365"
>
> # get the current date
> $curr_date = Get-Date
>
> # determine how far back we go based on current date
> $zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
> $delete_zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($delete_max_days)
>
> #$zip_date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).Month
>
> # filter files
> Get-ChildItem $log_path | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|
>
>   ForEach {
>     $Zip = $target_path + "{0:MMM}_{0:yyyy}.7z" -f $_.LastWriteTime
>     & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2  $Zip $_.FullName |Out-Null
>     If ($LastExitCode -eq 0) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
>   }
>
> $deletefile = Get-ChildItem $zip_path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $delete_zip_date } | Remove-Item
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Performance wise the grouping does IMO make no sense.
Files are stored, grouped and in the end read out and every single one zipped.

Determining the correct zip on the fly should be no problem.

```
# set folder path
$dump_path = "C:\Users\Desktop\02_2017"
# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).Month

# filter files
Get-ChildItem $dump_path |
  Where-Object {(($_.LastWriteTime).Month -le $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|
  ForEach {
    $Zip = "{0:MMM}_{0:yyyy}.7z" -f $_.CreationTime
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2 $Zip $_.FullName |Out-Null
    If ($LastExitCode -eq 0) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
  }
```

**Edit** changed

- the month name to abriviation and an underscore
- redirect output of 7z to Out-Null
- check `$LastExitCode` if zero delete file

Comment: OP mentioned he needs everything older than one month, so you may as well do `GCI $dump_path|?{$_.LastWriteTime.Month -le [datetime]::today.addmonths(-1).Month -and !$_.PSIsContainer}` and pipe that to your `ForEach`. Also, for consistency, either reference `LastWriteTime`, or `CreationTime`, but don't mix and match like that. Not blaming you, the OP did it, but if you're improving code you may as well go the extra mile.

Comment: Well if I think about it, the differing dates could make sense. Archiving a file not changed the last month is one thing but archiving with not altered creation time ( left aside that some apps rewrite the file without preserving the creation date) another.

Comment: @LotPings, your codes did not zip files which are older than 30 days into different zip files and name the zip files with the month and year based on created/modified day of the files.

Comment: @Mixer Ack, changed.

Comment: @LotPings, the updated version does not archive aaa files for some reasons. What is your suggestion to archive each set of files which created in the same month to mm_yyyy.7z where mm_yyyy is the created month and year of those files? Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

DateTime objects have an `.addMonths` method you can utilize instead of the `.addDays` method as well as a Month property.  You can observe all of the members by using `Get-Date | Get-Member`

```
# set folder path
$dump_path = "C:\Users\Desktop\02_2017"

# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month

# filter files
$files = Get-ChildItem $dump_path |
  Where-Object { (($_.LastWriteTime).Month -eq $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) }

$groups = Get-ChildItem $dump_path | 
  Where-Object { (($_.LastWriteTime).Month -eq $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) } | 
  group {"{0:MMMM} {0:yyyy}" -f $_.CreationTime}

ForEach ($group in $groups) {
  ForEach($file in $group.Group) {
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2 ($group.Name + ".7z") $file.FullName
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I archive files which were created in the same month separately?